# Apache mod_rewrite: /SomeFunkyText/cgi-bin/... ==> /cgi-bin/

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove some part of the url that comes before the cgi-bin part. I want to be able to use URLs like www.myserver.com/SomeFunkyText/cgi-bin/.... and proxy them to www.myserver.com/cgi-bin/...

I'm using mod_rewrite and my rule looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/cgi-bin/(.*)$  http://www.myserver.com/cgi-bin/$2 [P,L]
```

I also have a ScriptAlias directive:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/myserver/cgi-bin/
```

I'm getting:

You don't have permission to access /SomeFunkyText/cgi-bin/... on this server.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/(cgi-bin/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I have a script under cgi-bin. I see the script's source now - which is good progress, thanks! but its not executed, so I assume the ScriptAlias directive takes the URL before the RewriteRule? any way around that?

Comment: I tried replacing my ScriptAlias with: ScriptAliasMatch ^/?[^/]+/cgi-bin(.*) /var/www/myserver/cgi-bin$1 but that didn't work....

Comment: Try commenting `ScriptAlias` line for your testing.

Comment: Also I don't get when you say: `I see the script's source now - which is good progress`

Comment: I have scripts under the cgi-bin directory. When I use ScriptAlias they are executed, when I don't I just see their source. I want ScriptAlias to apply to this directory so that the scripts will be executed, instead of Apache returning their source. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes it answers my questions. Try this instead: `RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/(cgi-bin/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]`

Comment: In this case my users will see the redirect, which is why I was using P instead of R=301...

Comment: sorry, you're correct, I missed the part of enabling proxy_http. Thanks a lot for your help.